# CSS Transition not working accordingly

Tags: html, css, pug, css-transitions

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The hover is definitely working, as the top and bottom properties get changed, but the transition just isn't there.

```
.info{
  position:absolute;
  transition: opacity 2s; 
  top:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
  left:0px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  justify-content:center;
  display:none;
  opacity:0; 
}


.content ul li:hover .info{
  top:-10px;
  bottom:10px;
  opacity:1;
  display:flex;
}
```

Using jade, here is the markup

```
div.content  
      ul 
       each item in results2
          li
            img(src='images/portfolio/#{item.image_path}')
            div.info
              span #{item.title}
                p #{item.description}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the `display` property (`display:none`) that you have specified. If you remove `display:none` it should just work fine. `display` property cannot be transitioned.

Try:

```
.info{
   position:absolute;
   transition: opacity 2s; 
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
   left:0;
   background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   color:white;
   text-align:center;
   justify-content:center;
   opacity:0; 
}
```